# develop a Full Calendar application for Android Platform phones, using jQuery mobile with Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to develop a Calendar application for Android Platform phones, using jQuery mobile with Phonegap.
I want to use jQuery full calendar in my application, I have searched in many websites. But not able to find exact solution.
I know there must be some way around to use jQuery Full Calendar in jQuery Mobile.
by seesing some examples I have tried to use the jQuery Full Calendar Plugin but I was not able to call the fullCalendar() Method.`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"><script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/fullcalendar.js"><script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/fullcalendar.min.js"><script>`

Can any one help me in this....????
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: CAn you create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved this, Thanks to Stackoverflow. here is the working example of it! [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ZSd2C/)

```
 $(document).on('pageshow','#index',function(e,data){    
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```